# correct use of interal function and openmp

Tags: c++, loops, openmp

i have a for loop which calls an internal function :

```
some variables
for(int i=0; i< 10000000; i++)
    func(variables)
```

Basically, func gets a reference to some array A, and inserts values in A[i] - so i'm assured 
that each call to func actually tries to insert a value to a different place in A, and all other input variables stay the the same as they were before the for loop. So func is thread-safe.

Can i safely change the code to

```
some variables
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i< 10000000; i++)
    func(variables)
```

From what i understand from the openmp tutorials, this isn't good enough - since the openmp libraries wouldn't know that the variables given to func are really thread-safe, and so this would yield attempts to perform synchronization which would slow things up, and i would need to declare variables private, etc. But actually, when trying the code above, it seems to work indeed faster and parallel - is this as expected? I just wanted to make sure i'm not missing something.

The declaration of func :

```
 func(int i, int client_num, const vector<int>& vec)
```

Comment: Can you give the complete declaration of func(variables), as the answer will depend on the declaration.

Comment: i added in my question (a simplified) declaration of func. Also - further checks seem to show that actually my program with openmp yields different results than without - still not sure what and where is acting differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, OpenMP cannot magically determine the dependency on your code. It is your responsibility that the code is correct for parallelization.

In order to safely parallelize the for loop, `func` must not have *loop-carried flow dependences*, or inter-iteration dependency, especially for read-after-write pattern. Also, you must check there are no static variables. (Actually, it's much more complex to write down the conditions of the safe parallelization in this short answer.)

---

Your description of `func` says that `func` will write a variable into a *different* place. If so, you can safely parallelize by putting `pragma omp parallel for`, unless the other computations do not dependences that prohibit parallelization.

Your prototype of `func`: `func(int i, int client_num, const vector<int>& vec)`

There is a `vector`, but it's a constant, so `vec` should not have any dependency. Simultaneous reading from different threads are safe.

However, you say that the output is different. That means somethings were wrong. It's impossible to say what the problems are. Showing prototype of the function never helps; we need to know what kind of computations are done `func`.

Nonetheless, some steps for the diagnosis are:

- Check the dependency in your code. You must not have dependences shown in the below. Note that the array `A` has loop-carried dependence that will prevent parallelization:

`for (int k = 1; k <N; ++k) A[k] = A[k-1]+1;`

- Check `func` is re-entrant or thread-safe. Mostly, static and global variables may kill your code. If so, you can solve this problem by *privatization*. In OpenMP, you may declare these variables in `private` clause. Also, there is `threadprivate` pragma in OpenMP.

Answer (score 1):

You do not change anywhere your loop variable i, so it is no problem for the compiler to parallelize it. As i is only copied into your function, it cannot be changed outside.

The only thing you need to make sure is that you write inside your functions only to positions A[i] and read only from positions A[i]. Otherwise you might get race conditions.